# Can we Execute SQL Queries in JQuery

Tags: jquery, mysql

can we execute mySQL queries in jQuery Calllback functions & misc. functions

like simple query

```
UPDATE EMPLOYEE SET PAY = PAY + 500 WHERE E_ID = '32'
```

Comment: This is a pretty open question, you're asking how to do an AJAX update that increases the selected employee's pay by $500, right?  Then we'll need some other information, like what language/platform you're doing this one...the answer's different if you're using PHP vs ASP.Net vs ruby...

Comment: Actually, the answer is simply NO. JQuery can't make a connection to a MySQL server - you'll need a serverside script.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best thing you can do is to issue an AJAX request to a server and then execute this query using a server side code.

You can use [**jQuery.post()**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) in this case.

***Edit***

To get an overview of AJAX Read [**this**](http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/)

Read [**this**](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) to get and overview of AJAX methods in jQuery.

Write a server side logic to execute the SQL command, in a page. Then using AJAX issue a request to that page.

Sample Code

```
$(function(){
    // Bind a click event to your anchor with id `updateSal`
    $("#updateSal").click(function(){
        // get your employeeID
        var empID = "32"; 
        // issue an AJAX request with HTTP post to your server side page. 
        //Here I used an aspx page in which the update login is written
        $.post("test.aspx", { EmpID: empID},
            function(data){
                // callack function gets executed
                alert("Return data" + data);
        });

        // to prevent the default action
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 12):

While you could do this using a callback to a server-side script to execute your queries against MySQL, it would be a quick way to security holes.

Generating SQL queries from anything run on an end user device is a terribly bad idea.
Never trust anything a user sends you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

https://github.com/vinval/MyJSQL

How to:

```
$.jsql({
tbName:"EMPLOYEE",
set:["PAY=PAY+500"],
where:"E_ID=32"
}, function(){
//this is the callback 
})
```

Comment: See the previous comment.  This library allows a client to execute any SQL statement on the server.  Very dangerous.   I see nothing in the library to prevent anyone on a client from issuing SQL statements to the server with this library.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly access a database from javascript/jQuery but you can post to a web service on the server which can access the database.