# Get "td" values using the DOM and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, dom

I'm new to the world of coding ^_^ and I'm working on an existing open source solution called 'GLPI'. They're using the MVC method to manage their code, so I found it difficult to edit the code to not display some records in a table in the page. Also, I'm afraid I'll destroy the application which is why I decided to keep the old code and just add some additional PHP code at the end of the document to remove some `td` values from an HTML table if they're matching a MySQL query result:

1) What I really need is to get `td` values using the DOM and PHP from the table below.

For example (a table comprising two cells):

> PS: the table is loading the records from a MySQL query

```
    <form method="post" name="massiveaction_form" id="massiveaction_form"
    action="massiveaction.php">
        <div class="center">
          <table class="tab_cadrehov">
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                   <td>YassineKira</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td>YassineEdouiri</td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
    </form>
```

using this method:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML("users.html"); 
           .....................
           .....................
```

2) I would also like to execute a MySQL query to see if one of the retrieved `td` values has an id = 1, and then remove the `tr` containing the `td`. Something like this:

```
foreach (..(td value stored in an Array)... as $name ) {
   $IDq = mysql_query("select id from glpi_users where name = '".$name."'");
   $row = mysql_fetch_array($IDq);
   $ID = $row['id']; 
   if ($ID == 1) 
   {
       (....'tr->td'......).remove() ; 
   }

}
```

I'm using PHP above and I don't know if there is a combined PHP/jQuery solution that can handle this.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I am gonna take a shot here...

You can access the `td` values like this:

```
$(".tab_cadrehov td")
```

This will give you an array of elements which you can iterate using a loop or using `each`.

```
$(".tab_cadrehov td").each(function(){
    // $(this) will you each TD element
});
```

Comment: but how can i execute the Mysql query while i'm using jquery ?

Comment: Well, see this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234056/can-we-execute-sql-queries-in-jquery