# Using a function from a url in a jquery post request using Coldfusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coldfusion

newbie to coldfusion/programming here and I would love some help! So right now the basic overview is that I was instructed to use AJAX to take information from a form and insert it into my database. I have a component constructed with a query inside a function:

```
<cfcomponent>
    <cffunction name="set_all">
        <cfargument name="Title">
        <cfargument name="Description">
        <cfargument name="Branch">
        <cfargument name="DB">
        <cfargument name="Club">
        <cfargument name="Assignee">
        <cfquery name="set_all_query"  datasource="TicketFaster" username="TicketFasterLogin" password="TicketPassword">
            INSERT INTO Tickets (Title, Description, Branch, Club_Database, Club, Assignee, Assigner)
            VALUES ('#Title#', '#Description#', '#Branch#', '#DB#', '#Club#', '#Assignee#', '#session.username#');
        </cfquery>
   </cffunction>
```

And some jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function(f) {
        var Title = $("input[name=Title]").val();
        var Description = $("input[name=Description]").val();
        var Branch = $("input[name=Branch").val();
        var DB = $("input[name=DB]").val();
        var Club = $("input[name=Club").val();
        var Assignee = $("select[name=Assignee").val();
        $.post("ticketcomponent.cfc", {Title, Description, Branch, DB, Club, Assignee});
    });
});
```

So I'm taking in some inputted data (the variables) and then trying to call the set_all function from within the jquery function. Everything I've found online regarding jquery's post function simply writes their own function like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234056/can-we-execute-sql-queries-in-jquery), but I want to invoke a function from the referenced cfc file. Is this possible? Or is the only option to hard code my query into the function argument?

Comment: You will want to parameterize the values being passed to this method using `cfquery`, otherwise, you open yourself up to SQL injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the method with cfcname.cfc ?method=set_all

Shown here http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0ac4a-7fd9.html

The function has to have access="remote" so it's accessible to Ajax calls.

I didn't look at your jquery code but this is what you need to talk to the cfc.

Comment: Thank you!!! The access="remote" was not set, and now it works great. I appreciate the help.